# ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (447,), (1,))

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to extract tweets with specific mention and for that i am using

```
extracted_tweets[extracted_tweets['mentions']==['@amazon']]
```

But while doing so i am getting this error:

> ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (447,), (1,))

I have uploaded the data frame here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hb6k5mUc6ERXsG5_PgHuXxpMaDY5UOWe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try without the one-item list on the right-hand side: `extracted_tweets[extracted_tweets['mentions'] == '@amazon']`

Comment: This returned blank output

Comment: That suggests no rows meet the exact string criterion - but at least that cleared the error message!